# Change journal operations in .NET?

Tags: .net, windows, ntfs

I'm looking for the .NET/C# way of performing [Change Journal Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363801(VS.85).aspx) (without importing unmanaged code).

Any hints or RTM-links?

Answer (score 3):

This looks promising (and in C#):

http://mchangejournal.codeplex.com/

You have to download the Source code as there are no official Releases.  I was able to run the demo (on Windows 7), but not able to see which Files were changed.  This library may still be in its infancy.

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/Eyes_on_NTFS.aspx